# Workout Movement Counting using google_ml_kit flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-mlkit

I am creating a app using

> google_ml_kit

to create face recognition. I have successfully implemented the face recognition using **flutter(front end),node js(back end) and mongo database**. now I have to create Workout Movement Counting example(dumbbell count). can anyone please let me know it is possible with **google_ml_kit** package. If yes, please share some tips which will helps me a lot.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

The ML Kit's Android vision quickstart app provides an example to do rep counting with Pose Detection. https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

Please search for "Pose Detection" on the page linked above and see instruction about how to enable classification and counting in the demo app.

Here is the most related code: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/posedetector

The implementation is in Java, but it is just algorithm, so you should be able to convert it to Dart I guess (I am not familiar with Dart personally).

Answer (score 0):

**@all** I have implemented the dumbbell count using **tflite** plugin. If you need source code or support comment below.